# Nao estou conseguindo achar alguma maneira de limitar o tamanho geral do meu site

Tags: javascript, html, css

ao voce descer no site ele continua com infinitamente, eu ja tentei com width e height e ambos nao funcionaram do jeito esperado

https://github.com/Luccas-costa/Dusckb/tree/main/teste%20home-login

o html esta no home
o css esta no stylehome
e o js  esta no scriphome

Comment: Boas-vindas. Perguntas não podem depender de links externos e devem seguir o modelo [mcve]. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler a [help], após feito isso basta [edit] a pergunta e aguardar a comunidade avaliar se está adequada para o site. *Agradecemos a compreensão*.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Achei o erro. Lá no seus "script2.js", substitui o seu código pelo que vou mandar abaixo que vai funcionar de boa!

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    let value = window.scrollY

    if (value < 500) {
        leaf.style.top = value * -1.5 + "px"
        leaf.style.left = value * 1.5 + "px"
        hili5.style.left = value * 1.5 + "px"
        text.style.marginTop = value * 2.5 + "px"
        hili4.style.left = value * -1.5 + "px"
        hili1.style.top = value * 1 + "px"
    }

})
```

Comment: salvo eu muito obrigado